# Linear Span of $\Bbb R^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am stuck with this question from my assignment in which its given that $W_1 = L\{(1,1,0),(-1,0,2)\}$ and $W_2 = L\{(1,0,2),(-1,0,4)\}$ and it being asked to show that $W_1 + W_2 = \Bbb R^3$.

***Following are my conclusions:***

1. $\Bbb R^3$ only need three elements in its basis.
2. Elements in $W_1$ and $W_2$ are linearly independent with all possible combinations. I just need to choose any three of them for basis of $\Bbb R^3$.

Further in the question it is asked that a vector $v$ in $\Bbb R^3$ can be written in two different WAYS in the form $v = v_1+v_2$, where *$v_1$ belongs to $W_1$* and *$v_2$ belongs to $W_2$*. This is where I am lost, how could you define a vector in $\Bbb R^3$ with four basis element. (Two each from $W_1$ and $W_2$).

Comment: You can't. That's exactly why you can write it in two different ways.

Comment: Do you mean to say that one can take two elements from W1 and one element from W2 OR two elements from W2 and one element from W1 at a time?

Comment: Could you explain the notation $L\{(1,1,0),(-1,0,2)\}$?

Comment: L{(1,1,0),(-1,0,2)} means linear span of (1,1,0),(-1,0,2). (These are basis)

Answer (score 1):

We are given
\begin{align*}
W_1 &= \DeclareMathOperator{Span}{Span}\Span\{(1,1,0),(-1,0,2)\} & 
W_2 &= \Span\{(1,0,2),(-1,0,4)\}
\end{align*}
and we wish to prove that $\Bbb R^3=W_1+W_2$. This is equivalent to showing that the matrix 
$$
A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 &  0 & 0 &  0 \\
0 &  2 & 2 &  4 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
has rank three (why?). But a quick row-reduction shows that
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{rref}{rref}\rref A
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 3/2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1/2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus $A$ has rank three as required.